# Regex - Backreferencing - word delimiter?

Tags: regex, vim, backreference

In order to understand the **backreferencing** via the book **Mastering the regular expression,3rd edition** I created a file containing these two lines:

> the the
>
> the theft

after that I tried to execute this command:

```
:g/\([a-zA-Z]\+\) \1
```

so it showed me the two lines and it is obvious why

after that i tried to limit the result by catching only the first line

```
:g/\(\<[a-zA-Z]\+\>\) \1
```

it showed me also the two lines even when putting the delimiter `\<` `\>` of the word inside the parentheses.
the command below does what required (shows only the first line):

```
:g/\<\([a-zA-Z]\+\) \1\>
```

Any explanation why the delimiter inside the parentheses have no effect ?

Thanks

Comment: You are backrefercing the literal match from the first capturing group. Any zero-width assertions are not taken into consideration, no word boundaries, no start/end anchors, no lookbehinds or lookaheads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you are using `\(\<[a-zA-Z]\+\>\)`, it matches `the`. One thing to know that word boundaries are of `zero-width`. They can only be used to check some conditions (like for word boundary here), but they cannot be saved in any capturing groups. Capturing groups only saves the matched data and not *any* assertions.
>
> So, when you are backreferencing it using `\1`, it does not remember the word boundaries.

Instead what you mentioned, you have to use

```
:g/\(\<[a-zA-Z]\+\>\) \<\1\>
```

Quoting about word boundary from **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)**

*There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:*

> Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
> word character.
>
> After the last character in the string, if the last
> character is a word character.
>
> Between two characters in the string,
> where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: can you please explain the role of `\<` and `\>` regex in detail?

Comment: Sorry, I am not the OP.

Comment: @SilentMonk yeah..I forgot..was confused with name..happy to help